# Copying a BSTR into a char[1024]?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working on a web browser with c++ using IWebBrowser2. Declared on the top, outside any scope, I have this:

```
static char buf[1024];
```

In the documentcomplete event, I set the BSTR with:

```
CComBSTR bstrHTMLText;
X->get_outerHTML(&bstrHTMLText);
```

What I want to do is to copy bstrHTMLText value into buf (if bstrHTMLText length is > 1024 just fill buf and ignore the rest). every time documentcomplete fires.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BSTR` is secretly a pointer to a Unicode string, with a hidden length prefix sitting in front of the string data.  So, you can just cast it to `wchar_t*` and then convert that wide-character string to an ANSI string, e.g. using [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,
                    0, 
                    bstrHTMLText.m_str,
                    SysStringLen(bstrHTMLText.m_str),
                    buf,
                    sizeof(buf),
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
```

Comment: Careful with this. It will normally (perhaps always) work, but there are two potential gotchas: NULL is a valid BSTR, and BSTR's are not necessarily NULL-terminated (per the spec). Your solution will probably usually work in practice (and I've seen plenty of code do the equivalent), but it's not technically correct.

Comment: @Nick BSTR is null terminated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/692a42a9-06ce-4394-b9bc-5d2a50440168 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr